# source control for SQL Agent Jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, source-control

Our SQL Agent jobs execute different DTSX packages at various steps.
e.g:

```
\\DEVLserver\DTSX\package1.dtsx
```

I want to keep the agent job script in TFS but when I promote it is there any way to change or publish it as:

```
\\TESTserver\DTSX\package1.dtsx
\\PRODserver\DTSX\package1.dtsx
```

by using variables?